# Is it possible to have rounded cornered dialog box with scroll bar in jquery mobile? If yes how do I do that

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to have rounded corner dialog box in jquery mobile with scroll bar. But it is cutting off(right side) where scroll bar starts. Is it possible to have rounded corners with scroll bar. If yes how do I do that. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far. Even better create a jsFiddle reproducing the issue

Comment: check this one http://jsfiddle.net/b61z1wq0/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try like the following. Here i set the the content height to some pixels for scroll the content(for showing demo to you. it is not necessary).For rounded corners(increase the border radius you can create custom style for this).

CSS like:

```
.ui-dialog-contain {
    border-radius:15px;

}
.custom_height{
    height:100px !important;
}
```

Here is the **<kbd>[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b61z1wq0/3/)</kbd>**

Comment: Hi @Aravin, I tried your approach, but for some reason I didn't get the desired results. I am getting scrollbar starting at header not just for content and I am not getting rounded corners. Here is my jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mm125/a8hx7hpq/).

Comment: I didnt see any dialog in your fiddle..Please go through the docs http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages-dialog/ or check this http://jsfiddle.net/a8hx7hpq/2/